# 'Else' is an unexpected token in my Java code and the error I'm getting is that of an illegal type at line 18. What is wrong with my code?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm very new to Java and only started it yesterday, this is an exercise for my class and the code has to be similar to this one. I'm trying to create a simple log-in system in Java.
This is the error I am getting:
Error:(18, 11) java: illegal start of type

I've had a friend with similar code and it worked for him and he cannot specify why mine is not working.

I tried removing the curly brackets. I tried making different if statements and I tried putting round brackets around read.nextLine();

```
System.out.print("Type your username: ");
        String username = reader.nextLine();
        System.out.print("Type your password: ");
        String password = reader.nextLine();

        if (username = "Alex" && password = "mightyducks") {
            System.out.print("You are now logged into the system!");
        } else if (username = "Emily" && password = "cat")
            System.out.print("You are now logged into the system!");
        } else {
        System.out.print("Your username or password was invalid!");
        }
```

I simply want the program to show "You are now logged into the system!" when the correct password is given for Alex or Emily and for it to otherwise state: "Your username or password was invalid!".

Comment: `} else if (username = "Emily" && password = "cat")` <-- Missing `{`.

Comment: Unrelated to your error, but you have to call `String.equals` to compare `String` data

Comment: One `=` is assignment, and you don't use `==` to compare reference types (such as `String`). Also, hardcoded passwords are bad.

Comment: probably offtopic - Please use IDE (Netbeans, IntelliJ). It helps you to learn fast.

Comment: Voting to close. Before posting on Stack Overflow, work harder to compare such simple code to other code samples to discover this kind of trivial error. Stack Overflow is for specific programming problems, not “fix my code”. And use an IDE to help find such problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an opening brace missing at the end of this line:

```
} else if (username = "Emily" && password = "cat") {
```

And there are more errors. Use `.equals` to compare strings. `=` is an assignment which is totally wrong here.

Comment: I’m not sure answering such questions is helpful to the Stack Overflow community. If you feed the pigeons, you’ll get more pigeons.

Answer (score 1):

You have a missing opening brace for the first `else if`

Also you have to use `==` to compare instead of `=`. For strings and other types of objects you should use method `equals` as `==` compares the references and not the content.

```
if (username.equals( "Alex") && password.equals("mightyducks")) {
        System.out.print("You are now logged into the system!");
} else if (username.equals( "Emily") && password.equals("cat")){
        System.out.print("You are now logged into the system!");
} else {
        System.out.print("Your username or password was invalid!");
}
```

Comment: `==` compares the references (underlying addresses) of the String objects, whereas `equals` compares the String data itself.

Comment: ah, yes, I am doing C# lately and forgot. Fixed it.